# How to stop Inline-block from taking up more width than child elements

Tags: html, css

My `main` (colored in skyblue) element appears to be taking up more width than its child elements take up. It's display is set to `inline-block` which makes me curious why it's width isn't automatically set to `auto`. The immediate child elements have a display of `inline-block` as well but their width's combined = less than 100% width. What's going on here? How can I fix this and make the `main` element only take up as much space as it needs and not the whole 100% width?

```css
/* ///////////////////////////////// IMPORTS /////////////////////////////// */
@import url('https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css');

/* ///////////////////////////////// INITIAL /////////////////////////////// */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: left;
}
main p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[href="#"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 2.2%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: top;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body> <!-- red -->
    <main> <!-- skyblue -->
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>mmm random text caption.</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Is that a sheep or a goat?</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>A ram maybe? Is that wood tiling behind it?</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Definitly an animal on grass...on wood</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Umm. k.</p>
        </a>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Edit:** I thought it might be `main { width: 90%; }` but this seems to force `main` to take up 100% of the width. Making the issue worse.

**Edit 2: I could use flexbox or floats but I'm also curious as to is this standard `inline-block` behavior? Usually (in my experience) `inline-block` styled elements have a width of `auto` and adjust to the size of their content. Not being any larger than they need.**

Comment: remove the width from `main` and the width and margins from the `a` tags and `main`'s width is only as wide as the children inside.

Comment: `inline-block` defines a block level element that grows in width according to its contents. When it reaches the maximum amount of available width, it wraps. But it will continue to try to grow (so if its parent grows, it grows until it no longer has to wrap to accommodate all children). Picture them not as a parents shrinking down on their rows of children, but as parents that grow to have all children in one row. That's when they stop growing.

Comment: You should also avoid having margins or paddings in `%`, because those are relative to the current element. Most often than not, you want to have relations between parent margin/padding and children margin/padding. Normally you should use `rem` for this. Its constant throughout the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever the contents of an `inline-block` wrap, even once, it will take up the entire available width.

As for the desired behavior, I suppose you are looking for this: ...?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5vw;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .8rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #bbb;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a[href="#"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(33.3333% - 1.6rem);
  margin: .8rem;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main> <!-- skyblue -->
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>mmm random text caption.</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Is that a sheep or a goat?</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>A ram maybe? Is that wood tiling behind it?</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Definitly an animal on grass...on wood</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7WBWShL.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <p>Umm. k.</p>
        </a>
    </main>
```

---

Besides changing margins into `rem` from `%`, there is one other change I made to your original code and you might want to understand why:

Normally, you would think having

```
display:inline-block;
width:25%;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

on children should make them wrap in lines of 4, right?

But most often ***they do not***. Here's why: picture them as big letters in a line of text. Markup has line breaks and elements are placed on next row, for readability. Those line breaks and the tabs at the start of new lines are reduced by the browser into a single `space` character. And those `space` chars are not accounted for in `CSS`. The options are:

a) to suppress the spaces between `inline-block` elements using `html` comment blocks:

```
<parent><!--
  --><child></child><!--
  --><child></child><!--
  --><child></child><!--
  --><child></child><!--
  --><child></child><!--
--></parent>
```

This will work, they will be 4/row, no extra spaces added. Or...

b) use `float:left` on the children. If you also want the parent to expand its height (background) to include all the floating children, you should set `overflow:hidden` on it. Which is what I used in the above example and is the typical solution for floating inline containers.

Comment: This is pretty good. I guess `vw` units is a quick and dirty way to get around this. Thanks for explaining how this works in the comments as well.

Comment: I used `vw` to make the top/bottom ones equal with left/right as I liked them better equal. In this case, for left/right it actually means `5%`. But `5%` for top/bottom would have been relative to the height, not to the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to resolve the issue of the extra blank space on the right hand side.

Simply change the style of `.main`:

```
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: space-around;
   width: 90%;
   background-color: skyblue;
   text-align: left;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgbxr0sx/

Comment: I could use flexbox or floats but I'm also curious as to is this standard `inline-block` behavior. Usually (in my experience) `inline-block` styled elements have a width of auto and adjust to the size of their content. Not being any larger than they need.

Comment: @solacyon Think I've found the issue: `text-align: left;` - check my answer at the bottom.

Comment: hmm. But I still would like my centered elements to be left-aligned inside their container div as it is in my question. Only I would like the container to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove width of `main` and give fixed `width` to your child elements not `%`. Then you will get what you need.

You can't do it by giving `%` `width` to both parent and child element.

```
main {
  display: inline-block;
  /*width: 90%;*/
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: left;
}

a[href="#"] {
   width: 200px;
}
```